# How to send logs to logstash in a kubernetes cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logstash

I am running a logstash instance inside a k8s cluster. I setup the ingress rules and the tcp input. As a result I successfully curl the endpoint and I can see some curl logs on the cloud after I run this command `$ curl http://logstash-tcp.testing.com`

[image]

**The problem is that**

When I try to send logs manually `outside the k8s cluster` or `inside the logstash container`. My logs cannot hit the logstash. `$ echo "Test message" | logger -t logstash-tcp.testing.com -P 80`

**Below shows my setups:**

- elastic cloud setup and connected
- minikube version: v1.28.0
- kubectl version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"26", GitVersion:"v1.26.0", GitCommit:"b46a3f887ca979b1a5d14fd39cb1af43e7e5d12d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-12-08T19:58:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.19.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"25", GitVersion:"v1.25.3", GitCommit:"434bfd82814af038ad94d62ebe59b133fcb50506", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-10-12T10:49:09Z", GoVersion:"go1.19.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

- helm version: v3.10.3
- ubuntu: 20.04

I get the logstash from [artifact hub](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/elastic/logstash)

Here is my custom values:

```
persistence:
  enabled: false

logstashConfig:
  logstash.yml: |
    http.host: 0.0.0.0
    xpack.monitoring.enabled: true


logstashPipeline:
  uptime.conf: |
    input {
      exec {
        command => "uptime"
        interval => 30
      }
      gelf {
        port => 5959
      }
      tcp {
        port => 5960
        codec => json
      }
    }
    filter {
      mutate {
        add_field => {
          "environment" => "dev"
        }
      }
    }
    output {
      elasticsearch {
        index => "logstash-dev-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
      }
    }

ingress:
  enabled: true
  hosts:
    - host: logstash-gelf.testing.com
      paths:
        - path: /
          servicePort: 5959
    - host: logstash-tcp.testing.com
      paths:
        - path: /
          servicePort: 5960

service:
  # annotations: {}
  type: ClusterIP
  # loadBalancerIP: ""
  ports:
    - name: gelf-port
      port: 5959
      protocol: UDP
      targetPort: 5959
    - name: tcp-port
      port: 5960
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 5960

extraPorts:
  - name: gelf-port
    containerPort: 5959
  - name: tcp-port
    containerPort: 5960
```

`$ kubectl describe ingress`

```
Name:             logstash-elastic-logstash
Labels:           app=logstash-elastic-logstash
                  app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                  chart=logstash
                  heritage=Helm
                  release=logstash-elastic
Namespace:        default
Address:          192.168.39.184
Ingress Class:    nginx
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host                      Path  Backends
  ----                      ----  --------
  logstash-gelf.testing.com  
                            /   logstash-elastic-logstash:5959 (172.17.0.3:5959)
  logstash-tcp.testing.com   
                            /   logstash-elastic-logstash:5960 (172.17.0.3:5960)
Annotations:                meta.helm.sh/release-name: logstash-elastic
                            meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
Events:                     <none>
```

It seems that the route is setup and ready to use but the tcp logs cannot hit the logstash. Does anyone has experience on this?

Thanks